# Updating a leaderboard using a username

Tags: python, python-3.x

At the moment, I am trying to make a leaderboard in python which will automatically update within a file at the end of the code. So far, I have managed to make it so the file will open the file, sort it and then output it, then save it back to the file with the following code:

```
f = open('Leaderboard.txt', 'r')
leaderboard = [line.replace('\n','') for line in f.readlines()]
f.close()


leaderboard.sort(reverse=True)


for i in leaderboard:
    print(i)


with open('Leaderboard.txt', 'w') as f:
    for item in leaderboard:
        f.write("%s\n" % item)
```

However, this will not work like I need it to. The sorting works fine, as the number within the text file is before the username like so:

`12, User1
18, User2
14, User3
10, User4
30, User5`

However, I need it to replace a specific users score inside the array when they are higher than one of the highscores, e.g. if User3 got a score of 20, i would need to change the array to look like:

```
['12, User1','18, User2','14, User3', '10, User4', '30, User5']
```

before sorting it. Does anyone have any solutions that could help me here?

*Code for winner*

```
if Player1Points>Player2Points:
    Winner_Points = Player1Points
    Winner = user1
elif Player2Points>Player1Points:
    Winner_Points = Player2Points
    Winner = user2
```

Comment: These numbers are not sorted. Do you mean to re-arrange the order of the users according to their scores?

Comment: @blhsing I think its just find `User 3` and update newest high score changing `User 3` from `14 to 20`

Comment: No, I will be sorting it afterwards. I need to sort it after i have replaced whatever the winner got, as otherwise the code would become unsorted again

Comment: @Panda32 would just updating the list help you? Changing the list from  `['12, User1','18, User2','14, User3', '10, User4', '30, User5']
` to `['12, User1','18, User2','20, User3', '10, User4', '30, User5']?
`

Comment: @vash_the_stampede I need the program to check the item in the list that that user previously got, and then replace it with the new score if it is higher, and break if it isn't. I dont really control what the array looks like

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are trying to update that specific list with a new score for `User 3` you could use *enumerate* accompanied with `.split()`

If you create *tuple* `winner` with the new highscore and user who scored it, you can then compare that to the existing *list*, if the `UserX` matches and the new highscore is greater, then the old value `14, User3` is replaced with `20, User3` if the score is less nothing happens

```
l = ['12, User1','18, User2','14, User3', '10, User4', '30, User5']
winner = (20, 'User3')

for idx, item in enumerate(l):
    if item.split(', ')[1] == winner[1] and int(item.split(', ')[0]) < winner[0]:
            l[idx] = '{}, {}'.format(winner[0], winner[1])
    else:
        pass 

print(l)
```

> ```
> ['12, User1', '18, User2', '20, User3', '10, User4', '30, User5']
> ```

You could format your winner like this and use above code:

```
if Player1Points>Player2Points:
    Winner_Points = Player1Points
    winner = (Player1Points, 'User1')
elif Player2Points>Player1Points:
    Winner_Points = Player2Points
    winner = (Player2Points, 'User2')
```

Comment: What does the enumerate function do firstly? Also, how do i check it for all 5 users?

Comment: @Panda32 now check

Comment: @Panda32 enumerate returns the index and item for each item in the list, that way we can use the index `idx` to replace the existing item with `l[idx]`

Comment: Ill edit my question with the code that i use for the winner variable

Comment: If i change winner to (Winner_Points, Winner) will that work? There are 5 different users, so it may not be definitely user1/2

Comment: @Panda32 you would just have to set up your `if elif` so `winner` becomes a `tuple` that is in form `points, UserX`